# Deleting Photo from SD Card and GridView Layout

Tags: android, image, photo, android-sdcard, android-file

I have this code below and I would like it so that when I long click on my photo in my GridView, I get the option to Delete. This all works perfectly. However when I click delete, it doesn't actually delete the photo from my GridView or from the SD Card directory.

```
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.deletePhoto:
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Delete Photo")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        photoGrid.setSelection(i);
                        final File dir = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
                        dir.mkdirs();
                        File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean accept(File arg0, String arg1) {
                                return arg1.contains(".png");
                            }

                        });

                        File file = files[i].getAbsoluteFile();
                        file.delete();
                        Toast.makeText((MainActivity)getActivity(), "Photo deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
                break;
```

Does anybody have any ideas how to do this or what I'm doing wrong in my code? Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you are never calling / its never getting called   file.delete();

put  this inside onclick of dialog

```
                    File file = files[i].getAbsoluteFile();
                    file.delete();
                    Toast.makeText((MainActivity)getActivity(), "Photo deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

.

```
            case R.id.deletePhoto:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Delete Photo")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    photoGrid.setSelection(i);
                    final File dir = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
                    dir.mkdirs();
                    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

                    File file = files[i].getAbsoluteFile();
                    file.delete();
                    Toast.makeText((MainActivity)getActivity(), "Photo deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    });
               .setNeutralButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
            break;
```

Comment: File file = files[i].getAbsoluteFile();
                        file.delete();

Comment: @edwoollard you are using a dialog when you press ok, it should delete but you have called File file = files[i].getAbsoluteFile(); file.delete();  outside   onClick listner of ok button/positive button

Comment: No I haven't. I've fixed it now anyway. There was two issues, one was that photos from the camera save as .jpg, not .png, so it was never finding them. The other is that I was using int i as the position but that was wrong. Instead, I used this line: final AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); and then where I've called 'i', I called 'info.position'.

Comment: @edwoollard whatever you have pasted is wrong  you cant call file.delete inbetween ,when you are building a Dialog

Comment: I haven't. I've called it inside the onClick method. The way I know I'm right is because otherwise the i variable would not be found. It finds it and therefore it must be inside the method as i must be in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put

```
                    File file = files[i].getAbsoluteFile();

                    file.delete();
```

Inside

```
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {}
```

so that when you press ok button on dialog Delete Photo  it will delete the photo and call method delete;

Comment: Please explain to me how it is not inside the onClick method because to me it definitely looks like it is.

Comment: @edwoollard  before calling file.delete you have closed onclick `});`

Comment: No...that's the close of the FilenameFilter.